# Passing an executable command using USER environmental variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, security

Is it possible to pass some executable shell code by setting `env USER=..some code... ./script.sh`, given that the script itself either uses `echo $USER` or `tmpdir=/var/tmp/log-$USER`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: For code execution, see the part that says "up to arbitrary code execution vulnerabilities"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass shell code in an environment variable to a script, no problems, but the script would need to expect shell code in the variable and evaluate it as such:

See e.g. the difference between

```
$ env USER='$(echo hello)' bash -c 'echo "$USER"'
$(echo hello)
```

and

```
$ env USER='$(echo hello)' bash -c 'eval "echo \"$USER\""'
hello
```

In both of the above commands, a piece of code is passed in `$USER` to the `bash -c` script.  The code is a simple command substitution that would output the string `hello` if evaluated, and the calling shell would *not* evaluate the command substitution since it is a string within single quotes.  The first `bash -c` script does not evaluate the string, so it prints the shell code.  The second `bash -c` script evaluates the passed string as part of a call to `echo`, and therefore prints `echo` (it basically runs `echo "$(echo hello)"`.

This way of solving your issue is brittle and dangerous, as it allows a user to pass arbitrary shell code into your script (in fact, it *relies* on being passed code and you execute it unconditionally). It's a typical code injection vulnerability.

What I think that you want to do is to pass a *string*, not shell code:

```
$ env USER="$(echo hello)" bash -c 'echo "$USER"'
hello
```

Here, the variable `USER` is set to the string `hello` before calling the `bash -c` script (since the shell would expand the command substitution within the double quotes). The script then takes the string and echoes it.  In your case, the script would take the string and use it as part of a pathname.

The point is that the string is computed by the user before the script gets it.